# Data from REST service shows symbology for items not on my map

Tags: qgis, symbology, cartography, ubuntu, web-service

I am using QGIS 3.4 to display eelgrass data from this website:

https://geo.wa.gov/datasets/8ef27802b6cf4b61b814c80dd91d6e9e.

To get the specific layer I need I use this link to connect to an ArcGIS mapping layer and add layer #42:

https://gis.dnr.wa.gov/site3/rest/services/Public_Aquatics/WADNR_PUBLIC_AQR_NS_HBTT/MapServer

This adds the data to my QGIS project but the data are classified into two classes called *continuous* and *patchy*.  I would like to remove *continuous* from the symbology and legend as this class does not appear in my area of interest.  I cannot figure out how to alter the text or remove *continuous* from the legend in QGIS using the layers symbology.  I have tried to download the data as a TIFF file for my area of interest and this creates a TIFF file of junk with only 2.5KiB of space.

How do only display the *patchy* class of data in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS use **'ArcGIS Feature Service'** rather than ArcGIS Map Service.

Then you will be able to retrieve the vector data and style/export features as you wish.

Example:
[image]

(QGIS 3.14 used here)